# How to stay logged in to Atlassian sites like JIRA, FishEye, Crucible, etc. in Chrome?

Tags: macos

The problem I'm trying to solve is that my company has set the login timeout for our internal Atlassian websites -- such as Confluence, FishEye, Crucible and JIRA -- at 24 hours. This means that every single day I get logged out, and need to log back in.

Some times this happens while I'm in the middle of editing a wiki page, or querying JIRA, and I lose my progress. Other times, it's just an annoying step of having to click the "Log In" button before I can resume what I was doing. Thankfully, the Atlassian web apps remember my username/password, and do a reasonably good job of redirecting me back to the page I was on.

My company is unwilling to increase the 24h timeout to something more reasonable. ***So how do I automatically stay logged in?*** I'm on Mac OS X, using Google Chrome for my browser.

The one idea I've come up with is to write a Chrome Extension which will automatically do something behind the scenes to keep me logged in. Would updating the expiration date on a cookie suffice? Or is the auto-logout time stored on the server? *Worst* case scenario, I could fetch the page in the background (or open another tab) and submit the login form if prompted, which would log me back in.

My goal here is to be able to use these internal websites, and rarely (once/month would be ok) be prompted to login. I can't be the first person to run into this annoyance!

Comment: use 1password [link to there site](https://agilebits.com/onepassword)

Comment: @Floris497 how does that solve my problem? Will that program automatically check if I'm logged out every hour, and re-sign me in without me having to do anything?

Comment: would refreshing the page reset the timers?

Comment: @prusswan I don't think it would, because if that were the case then I wouldn't get logged out every day since I'm using these sites every day. I think the 24h time limit is like Gmail's 2 week logout, in that it ignores how often I'm using the site.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a tolerable workaround for this problem. I installed the [LastPass Chrome Extension](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php?fromwebsite=1), and it automatically submits the login form (with username and password filled in) whenever I'm logged out and prompted.

A better approach would be to avoid having to re-login so often, but this will do for now. I'll leave this question unanswered for a few days, in case anyone else has a better solution.

Comment: Turns out, the problem was specific to Google Chrome. I didn't get timed out with Firefox, and when I deleted all my cookies for our Atlassian sites, it fixed the problem. I think there was also a setting on our server that SysOps had accidentally configured with a 1 hour timeout. I no longer need to use LastPass. Still not sure why this wasn't affecting other people on my team, though. Should I delete this question, accept my own answer, or leave it open?